# can't get hapi reply headers to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, hapi.js

I'm trying to get [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-auth-jwt2) for hapi to work, I'm getting a difficulty with sending the token back to the client. 
I'm trying to send it in the header like the example:

in example from: [jwt](https://github.com/dwyl/learn-json-web-tokens/blob/master/example/lib/helpers.js)

```
res.writeHead(200, {
'content-type': 'text/html',
'authorization': token});
```

I'm trying something like :

```
reply('Here is token').header({
    'content-type': 'text/html',
    'authorization': token}).code(200);
```

But I get an error

> TypeError: Uncaught error: key.toLowerCase is not a function

Somehow I can't find an example of how to do this. I'm suppose to send the Token back to the 'client app' in the header, but can't find a way of doing it with hapi. Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for chaining is like this

```
return reply('Here is token')
    .type('text/html')
    .header('X-authorization', token)
    .code(200);
```

Answer (score -2):

Usually people send the token in the body of the response back to the client along with some user information for front end convenience, so your reply would probably just look more like this

```
const authenticatedUser = {
  id: 'testuser',
  firstName: 'Simon',
  lastName: 'Prince',
  token: 'bearer supersecretjwttokenhere'
};
return reply(authenticatedUser);
```

Your client application will get that JSON response, grab the token, store it in local storage and update the UI with the user information from the response.